# When trying to set parameter of type byte[] in Google Endpoints object a String is excpected

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I created an Object which is sent through Google Cloud Endpoints. Among its parameters there is one parameter of type byte[] with its getter and setter methods.

The problem is when I want to set the byte[] parameter in my app it expects somehow a parameter of type String? Does it want me to encode the byte array or what is the reason for that strange error?

When I get the parameter from the dataObject it is of type byte[] and everything is fine. I am really confused!

My Object is DataPackage defined in my Backend

```
 ...
 private byte[] imageThumbnail;

 public void setImageThumbnail(byte[] imageThumbnail) {
    this.imageThumbnail = imageThumbnail;
}

public byte[] getImageThumbnail() {
    return imageThumbnail;
}
```

Then in my app I try to set the imageByteArray

```
 dataPackage.setImageThumbnail(byteThumbnail); // gives error that String is expected
```

And this works fine

```
 dataPackage.getImageThumbnail() // is of type byte[]
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code and any related LogCat messages printed out?

Comment: I'm faced the same problem. Did you solve it ?

Comment: I solved it by not using the datastore to save images at all. You could use the endpoints to send images when you decode them to a Base64 String but sooner or later you will find out that it takes a lot of time(1 Mb ~ 10 Seconds) to up or download the image. I recommend to use the Blobstore with a Servlet for any images it's way more faster and not in your Upload/Download Qouta!

Answer (score 2):

While it may not be your first choice, is it possible to use the byte[] constructor for a string and pass it that? An example of how to do so can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java)

Essentially the relevant part of that question/answer is this:

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 99, (byte)97, (byte)116}; //This could also be your byte array
String s = new String(b, "US-ASCII"); // US-ASCII might need to be something else
```

and then the opposite process:

```
String s = "some text here"; //The string from dataPackage.getImageThumbnail()
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); //Might need to be some other byte formatting
```

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Good useful information, though it does not address the OP question.  It is kind of sad that the best answer Marcel found to what seems a simple question was `don't do that`.

Answer (score -1):

You should decode and encode using the Base64 class of from the Android framework.

```
String encodedBitArray = Base64.encodeToString(imageThumbnail, Base64.DEFAULT);

byte[] decodedArray = Base64.decode(encodedBitArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If you want to convert the byte array to a Bitmap you need to do the following :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

[SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587452/1824521)